# Recursive call to a duplicated Bash script, making it unable to access the assets

Tags: xml, bash, xslt, saxon

***Edit*** : This post is now addressed in a new, as the problem as to be presented slightly differently. It's here : [How can I efficiently run XSLT transformations for a large number of files in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141161/how-can-i-efficiently-run-xslt-transformations-for-a-large-number-of-files-in-pa)

I'm stuck in my attempts of parallelizing a process, and after some decent time spent on it I'd like to request some help ...

Basically, I have a lots of XML files to transform with a specific XSLT sheet. But the sheet uses a call to an (very slow) API to fetch additional data, and taking the whole batch of XMLs in 1 go will take (very) long.

Therefore I splitted all the files from the original "input" folder into subfolder containing each around 5000 XML files, and I copied the following Bash script inside each subfolder too:

```
for f in *.xml
do
  java -jar ../../saxon9he.jar -xsl:../../some-xslt-sheet.xsl -s:$f
done
```

And I call each process, for each folder, from the "root" folder containing altogether the "input" folder, the Saxon library and the XSLT sheet :

```
find input -type d -exec sh {}/script.sh \;
```

But I get this error:

```
Unable to access jarfile ../../saxon9he.jar
```

I suppose it comes form the fact that I'm operating from the "root" folder, when the scripts being called are lower in the directories. I could solver the problem (if I'm correct) by copying all the assets in each subfolder, but I found the solution making my current approach even clumsier.

Thanks to anyone who might have an idea and make me understand this !

Comment: You are using a _relative_ PATH in your commands. So either use an _absolute_ PATH or retrieve the location to a variable and then use it.

Comment: Aside: If you're invoking it with `sh`, it's not a *bash* script, it's a POSIX sh script.

Comment: Second aside: use `-s:"$if"` or `"-s:$f"` to ensure that an XML file with spaces in its name doesn't generate multiple arguments.

Comment: Third aside: Support for `{}` as an argument substring, rather than a distinct argument in and of itself, is not guaranteed by the standard for POSIX `find`.  It's safer not to rely on that capability.

Comment: (and, err, **why** are you copying your bash script into all those directories, instead of just calling it from one place?)

Comment: Thanks for all these comments @charles-duffy, but none are really bringing solutions actually. And, aside, POSIX is still a Bash mode it seems https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html . And I proceeded this way because I'm a beginner and it avoids me from giving a bottom-up absolute path of the source files

Comment: Thanks @zx485 I'll try this, but I'm not sure how to get a bottom-up absolute path of the source files ...

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault, yes, if I meant to give you a solution, it would be an answer, not a comment. I don't understand *why* you're doing things the seemingly-nonsensical way that you are enough to provide a solution. (which is to say, my solution boils down to "don't do that").

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault, yes, there **is** an optional POSIX mode available for bash, but it's providing a smaller, *different* language in that mode, not the full bash shell language with all of its extensions. And in many operating systems -- including Debian and Ubuntu -- `/bin/sh` is not bash-in-POSIX-mode but a different shell altogether, such as `ash` or `dash`.

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault, with respect to getting an absolute path, running `root=$PWD` from the directory with the library and sheet will do; then, if you `export root`, any subprocess will be able to look up that directory as `$root`.

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault, ...that said, I'll hazard that if you asked a version of this question that **didn't** assume that parallelizing things required splitting your files up into a bunch of subdirectories, you might get a useful answer that worked without that overhead.

Comment: That's perfectly accurate, I just don't know how to start from for the subject of such question. I assumed I'd get a solution based on my current approach (splitting the files in 5K chunks is based on some perf test, but it is a "static" approach indeed), and I'd refine it later on. How would you put it ?

Comment: Not sure how I'd ask the question, but my answer to it might look something like: `printf -- '-s:%s\0' *.xml | xargs -P 16 -n 1 -0 java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:some-xslt-sheet.xsl` -- if we wanted 16 processes running at a time, and had everything (the XML files, the stylesheet, and the jar) in the same directory; tune to taste.

Comment: (That said, spinning up a JVM is pretty heavy-weight -- if performance were important, I'd try to find a solution that could reuse the same JVM to process more than one XML file; that way JIT optimizations have time to be applied).

Comment: Actually, in terms of how to ask the question -- "How can I efficiently run XSLT transformations for a large number of files in parallel?" might do. That way, anything that falls into the category of performance/efficiency optimizations (such as reusing JVMs) is in-scope. Might scope the question further to specify Saxon if your templates are known not to be compatible with libxml/libxslt (and it's probably worth figuring that out and including it in the question).

Comment: Thanks Charles, it is indeed working with this, very neat! The 8 cores are 100% but the Ram has room for way more ... I'll try with - P 32? I'll re-post my question with your solution as a dialogue kickstarter, in a new post, with the proposed title, if you want. Or feel free to do so ?

Comment: Feel free to do so yourself.  Hopefully you get an answer that covers reusing the JVMs -- I'd expect that to be a very large throughput boost, vs one-JVM-per-input.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you really don't want to initialize a new Java VM to run each transformation: this is typically going to take much longer than running the actual transformation. To put this in perspective, for "typical" transformations you will often see Java initialization time 3 seconds, stylesheet compilation time 300ms, transformation time 10ms. So if you can find a way to do it that only initializes Java and compiles the stylesheet once, your total time for 10K documents is going to be 2 minutes rather than 10 hours.

There are various ways to achieve this but they all involve using something other than a shell-script to control the process. The simplest, in my view, is to control it from XSLT itself, by using the collection() function to access all the files in the directory. This has an added bonus, if you're using Saxon-EE, that the files will be processed (parsed) in parallel using all the cores on your machine, which can speed things up by another factor of 4 or so. You just need to add an entry point to the stylesheet something like:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///my/dir?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')!saxon:discard-document(.)">
    <xsl:result-document href="....">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The saxon:discard-document call is optional, but because it makes documents eligible for garbage collection, means that you are less likely to run out of memory.

Another approach to writing the control loop is to use a specialized shell such as xmlsh.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards this solution. Controlling the loop from XSLT itself with the Saxon-EE library makes sense indeed, I'll play with that to see the perf. No issue with the amount of input XML files, with the collection() function ?

Comment: The only issue can be memory. Hence the discard-document() call to make sure the documents aren't locked in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way to enter the directory for each argument and call the script therein:

```
for d in */script.sh
do
  (
    cd "$(basename "$d")"
    sh ./script.sh
  )
done
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the path to the JAR not being valid from the location where the script is being run.

Comment: Yes, I think it does.  I assume that the given path in the script (`../../saxon9he.jar`) is correct from the location of this script.  The original version tried to use this path from the directory above this one, and that was wrong.

Comment: Ahh! Plausible. If that were the problem, then the OP would just need to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`. By the way, I'd suggest `exec sh ./script.sh` -- that way we're consuming the subshell instead of creating a new subprocess. Or, even better, `. ./script.sh`, in which case we're not starting a new shell at all, but using the copy forked off by the subshell created by the parenthesis to run the script.

Comment: OP doesn't really need any `find` at all for this task.  But yes, if using `find` was wanted, `-execdir` would solve the issue, I think.

Comment: (as an aside, inside a tight loop, you might want to avoid subshell overhead -- meaning the performance overhead of spawning off a subshell and then calling the external `basename` in that subshell might be measurable, as opposed to the more efficient `cd "${d%/*}"`).